# How do I create a list of lists of pairs ordered and grouped by the second elements?

Tags: haskell

```
sorteerOpY :: (Int, Int) -> [[(Int, Int)]]
sorteerOpY (x,y) = [[(a,b)]|b<-[0..y-1],a<-[0..x-1]]
```

This is what I have right now, `sorteerOpY (2,3)` results in:

```
[[(0,0)],[(1,0)],[(0,1)],[(1,1)],[(0,2)],[(1,2)]]
```

But this is what I want it to result in:

```
[[(0,0),(1,0)],[(0,1),(1,1)],[(0,2),(1,2)]]
```

What do I need to change so that my list gets created correctly?

Comment: Change `[[(a,b)]|b<-[0..y-1],a<-[0..x-1]]` into `[[(a,b)|a<-[0..x-1]]|b<-[0..y-1]]`

Comment: Thank you! I see what you did there, it looks so easy now, I can't believe I've been breaking my head over this.

Comment: No worries! Glad to have helped. :)

Comment: @Alec that should have been an answer…

Comment: @Zeta I disagree. An answer is accompanied with an explanation.  Like what you just did. :)

Comment: @Alec: Yeah, but my answer missed the nested list comprehension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can think of list comprehensions as `[[(a, b) | b <- [0..y-1]]| a<-[0..x-1]]` like this:

```
for every b <- [0..y-1]       
   xs <- for every a <- [0..x-1]
      add (a, b) to the resulting list
   add xs to the resulting list
```

So if `a` in `(a, b)` should change faster, you need to swap those lines:

```
for every a <- [0..x-1]
   xs <- for every b <- [0..y-1]
      add (a, b) to the resulting list
   add xs to the resulting list
```

which directly results in `[[(a,b) | a <- [0..x-1]]| b <- [0..y-1]]`.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood the question, look at Alec's comment because that does what i wanted.

Comment: @ergoforce Whoops. You're right. I was somewhat in a hurry yesterday and missed the nested list comprehension.